# Increase the size of a partition root ubuntu

Tags: server, putty, filezilla

I have a space problem with an ubuntu server created via Ovh

I can not increase the size of my system partition.

Here is what a df -h returns

```
root@0123456:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G  4.9G   14G  28% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G  8.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G   23M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md3        3.6T   69M  3.4T   1% /home
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

Without deleting the data in this root disk

I have a free space in  /dev/md3  (3.7 TB)

I have access with filezilla and putty

It is a server dedicated on ovh

Comment: What is your problem? You still have 14G available in your root partition, are there any error messages?

Comment: I have 14 GB because I deleted a LOG file with odoo 
And I have a problem that the file grows up quickly |  I want to take advantage of the space to rot
Without deleting anything help me

Comment: The easiest way: Find out where the log file is situated. Let's say, it is `/path/to/the/file.log`.  Then move the file (while it is not accessed!) to some place in `/home`: `mkdir /home/somedir && mv /path/to/the/file.log /home/somedir/` (might be you'ld have to do this with root permission). Then  create a symlink to the file: `ln -s /home/somedir/file.log /path/to/the/file.log`. Alternative, you could do this with the whole directory the file is in: `mkdir /home/somedir && mv /path/to/the/ /home/somedir/ && ln -s /home/somedir/the/ /path/to/`.

Comment: If it is possible to modify the path for the logfile (and maybe other files/directories) in the odoo configuration to sit somewhere below `/home`, this would be the best solution.

Comment: It is not possible to change the path in home because there is no right || 
I can create the symbolic link  but  the file log in /var/log/odoo it is always on increase || 
think, Is there another solution

Comment: There are many other solutions; but if you don't have the right to a) move folders b) modify the configuration of odoo; you probably don't have the right to modify disks and partitions....

Comment: think @ridgy ||  I have the right to root || 
I have an access with filezilla ||**The link is create mail the file size and still increasing**